# ruby array of hash merge array values based on key

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, merge

I have some questions about an `array` of `hash` in `ruby`.

Example :

```
a = [{236=>1}, {236=>1}, {237=>1}]
```

I want get result like this :

```
a = [{236=>2}, {237=>1}]
```

How do I merge an `array` of values based on their `key` in `ruby`?

Comment: You should not change the question after you've posted it. It renders answers and comments meaningless.  You can add to your question, it which case it's generally a good idea to identify it as an edit. You'll see I did that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. Here's one that uses the form of the method [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the values of keys present in both hashes being merged:

```
a.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g["order_detail_id"]=>g) { |_,oh,ng|
    { "order_detail_id" =>g["order_detail_id"],
      "quantity"=>oh["quantity"]+ng["quantity"] } } }.values
  #=> [{"order_detail_id"=>236, "quantity"=>2}, 
  #    {"order_detail_id"=>237, "quantity"=>1}]
```

Another approach uses [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
a.group_by { |h| h["order_detail_id"] }.map { |id, a|
  { "order_detail_id"=>id, "quantity"=>a.reduce(0) { |t,g|
    t + g["quantity"] } } }
  #=> [{"order_detail_id"=>236, "quantity"=>2}, 
  #    {"order_detail_id"=>237, "quantity"=>1}]
```

**Edit:** monoy has asked how one can merge:

```
a = [{236=>1}, {236=>1}, {237=>1}]
```

When you have hashes with a single key-value pair, it's often easiest to first convert them to arrays, to have easy access to the key and value:

```
b = a.map(&:to_a)
  #=> [[[236, 1]], [[236, 1]], [[237, 1]]]
```

Unfortunately, this has three levels of arrays, where we want just two. We could write:

```
b = a.map(&:to_a).flatten(1)
  #=> [[236, 1], [236, 1], [237, 1]]
```

but an easier way is:

```
b = a.flat_map(&:to_a)
  #=> [[236, 1], [236, 1], [237, 1]]
```

Again, we can merge the arrays several different ways. This is one which uses a hash with a default value of zero:

```
b.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k,v),h| h[k] += v }
  #=> {236=>2, 237=>1}
```

We have:

```
enum = b.each_with_object(Hash.new(0))
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[236, 1], [236, 1], [237, 1]]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can convert this enumerator to an array to see what values `each` will pass into the block:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[[236, 1], {}], [[236, 1], {}], [[237, 1], {}]]
```

We can use [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to obtain each value of the enumerator, and assign the block variables to that value. The first passed to the block is:

```
(k,v),h = enum.next
  #=> [[236, 1], {}] 
k #=> 236 
v #=> 1 
h #=> {}
```

so in the block we execute:

```
h[k] += v
```

which evaluates to:

```
h[236] += 1
```

which means:

```
h[236] = h[236] + 1
```

The hash `h` is presently empty, so it doesn't have a key `236`. Therefore, `h[236]` on the right side of the expression returns the hash's default value of zero:

```
h[236] = 0 + 1
```

so now:

```
h #=> {236=>1}
```

Now pass the next element into the block:

```
(k,v),h = enum.next
   #=> [[236, 1], {236=>1}] 
k #=> 236 
v #=> 1 
h #=> {236=>1}
```

so now the default value is not used when we execute the expression in the block:

```
h[k] += v
#=> h[k] = h[k] + v
#=> h[236] = h[236] + 1
#=> h[236] = 1 + 1
```

so now:

```
h #=> {236=>2}
```

The third and last element of the enumerator is now passed to the block:

```
(k,v),h = enum.next
   #=> [[237, 1], {236=>2}] 
 k #=> 237 
 v #=> 1 
 h #=> {236=>2}

 h[k] += v
   #=> h[k] = h[k] + v
   #=> h[237] = h[237] + 1
   #=> h[236] = 0 + 1 # the default value of 0 applies

 h #=> {236=>2, 237=>1}
```

and we are finished.

Comment: hi @Cary Swoveland how to merge array of hash like this :

[{236=>1}, {236=>1}, {237=>1}]

Answer (score 2):

I find this way readable:

```
a = [{236=>1}, {236=>1}, {237=>1}]
merge_with_addition = -> x,y {x.merge(y){|_,old,new|old+new}}

p a.reduce(&merge_with_addition) #=> {236=>2, 237=>1}
```

Comment: The output is a Hash, not an array of hashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [{234 => 1}, {235 => 1}, {234 => 1}]

hashes = array.map(&:to_a).flatten
  .each_slice(2).with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k, v), h|
  h[k] += v
}.each_with_object([]) { |(k, v), a|
  a << { k => v }
}
```

Comment: No need to delete you can just edit my answer or comment the fix. Or ill just write one.

Comment: Too true. Too true. Nice spot.

Comment: Sorry. Yeah. You are right. (Making all kinds of mistakes :p)

Comment: Ok just tested. Noticed that to_a gives an array of aarry, of course, so i decided to flatten and use each slice, but you could also map first or flatten on the array of array. Or you could just adjust the block variables. Anyway, this seems to work.